# Drupal forums ready for action?

Tags: 7, updating, importing-exporting, nodes

I have an active site running drupal 5 with phpbb2 for the forums.

## QUESTIONS

- Is Drupal 7 capable of supporting this forum functionality (or most of it)?
- What would be a recommended upgrade path to reach that goal?
- What modules would be necessary or recommended?